# Overflow auto doesn't work because children is making parent bigger

Tags: html, css

My goal is to code a simple design with 2 columns - first of 250px width and second of the rest of free space.
Inside the second column may be a huge element that must take 100% of parent width and be scrollable horizontally if is bigger than parent.

This is my CSS:

```
.layout {
  display: flex;
  padding: 20px;
}

.sidebar {
  width: 250px;
  background-color: red;
}

.content {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.largeBox {
  overflow-x: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.large {
  width: 900px;
  height: 50px;
  background: rgb(34, 193, 195);
}
```

It doesn't work because it makes first column to shrink to it's content instead of taking 250px. When i make it min-width then the entire page gets scrollbar.
How to implement this design?
Link to the code: https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-meadow-c9txz1

Comment: _"it makes first column to shrink to it's content instead of taking 250px"_ - so forbid it from shrinking then, `flex-shrink: 0` ...?

Comment: @CBroe it will prevent shrinking but it adds the scrollbar to the entire page, so there is another issue

Comment: You are using `width: 900px;` inside `.large`. And scrollbar appear when width was less then 900px

Comment: @KiriloLozitsky I don't want the page scrollbar to appear on any screen at all. I only want the 900px element to be scrollable if it is too large. How to do this?

Comment: @Minmoid add `overflow-x: auto;` to `.content` and comment /*   width: 900px; */ inside `.large`

Comment: @KiriloLozitsky I don't want the content to be scrollable. I want only the large element inside content to be scrollable. 900px is added on purpose

Comment: @Minmoid https://codepen.io/lozitsky/pen/zYRxxvP

Comment: @KiriloLozitsky It doesn't solve my issue. You just removed the 900px element. I want the 900px element to be there, just to make it scrollable if there is not enough space.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to replace `width` with `min-width`

```css
.sidebar {
    min-width: 250px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Using min-width prevents from shrinking but adds the scrollbar to the entire page, so there is another issue

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.layout {
  display: flex;
  padding: 20px;
}

.sidebar {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  width: 250px;
  background-color: red;
}

.content {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.largeBox {
  overflow-x: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.large {
  width: 900px;
  height: 50px;
  background: rgb(34, 193, 195);
  background: linear-gradient(
    106deg,
    rgba(34, 193, 195, 1) 0%,
    rgba(253, 187, 45, 1) 35%,
    rgba(45, 253, 149, 1) 100%
  );
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="layout">
      <div class="sidebar">
        <p>sidebar</p>
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <p>this is epic</p>

        <div class="largeBox">
          <div class="large"></div>
        </div>

        <p>Thank you!</p>
      </div>
        
  </div>  
</body>
```

You need use `flex-shrink: 0` within `.sidebar`.

Comment: Same issue as with other anwsers - it prevents from shrinking but it adds scrollbar to the entire page.

Comment: @Minmoid. look at this latest solution.

Comment: It adds page scrollbar. I don't want page to be scrollable

Comment: @Mimoid maybe you need hide scrollbar. https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/css/css+hide+scrollbar+but+allow+scroll

Comment: @Mimoid `.largeBox {
  overflow-x: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
  scrollbar-width: none;
}

.largeBox::-webkit-scrollbar { 
  width: 0 !important 
}

.large {
  min-width: 900px;
  height: 50px; ...`

Comment: I don't think you understand what I'm trying to achieve. The 900px div must be scrollable if there is not enough space for him. Imagine this is some photo that you do not want to cut. At the same time I don't want the page to be scrollable. The only thing I want the scroll on is this 900px div. And your answer doesn't help with this

Comment: @Mimoid do you need to scroll x or y? You can add `overflow-x: auto;` to `.large`, but delete elsewhere if you need to scroll x inside `.large`

Comment: As written in my primary question - I want to scroll horizontally, so by x. And your last answer doesn't work either.

Comment: You can also hidden, scroll y. `.largeBox {
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}`

Comment: It changes nothing. Did you even test it or you are just guessing?

Comment: Most likely, you are confusing some fundamental concepts. And you need something other than overflow. https://codepen.io/lozitsky/full/zYRxxvP

Comment: Two comments above I explained what is my goal. Using overflow was just a way of doing it by me, not a necessary thing. The codepen you sent still has the same issue - it adds page scrollbar and the layout sitcks out of the screen on smaller screen. I don't want page scroll, I want the whole layout te be visible and only the 900px div to be scrollable.

Comment: @Mimoid. You may need to enable `span` inside `.large` and allow it to overflow. Look at this: https://codepen.io/lozitsky/full/zYRxxvP

Comment: Doesn't work correctly - it cuts inner scrollbar. I found a solution which is to add `width: calc(100% - 250px)` to the content and it works

Comment: I have given you a comprehensive answer to your question. So ask the right questions to get a more accurate answer. If you need to resize to fit the screen, use a media query. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: I agree, the question in title was inaccurate, but I think the description of the post was on point. Summary of my post is: "How to code this layout without any side effects?". And all of mine and yours solutions were causing side effects (eg. page scroll) until I figured out `width: calc(100% - 250px)`. Nonetheless, thank you for your help

Comment: But it is better to start with the relative width of the screen, rather than setting a hard-coded value. You can declare the main parent element as 100vw (100% of the screen width) and then use the percentage for the child elements.

Answer (score -1):

Would you consider shifting to CSS Grid? Your life will get exponentially easier when you start using 'fr' units, i.e. remaining space.

```
.layout {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 250px 1fr;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.sidebar {
}

.content {
}
```

Then, to hide the scrollbar:

```
scrollbar-width: none; // firefox
&::-webkit-scrollbar { display: none; } // Chrome, Safari and Opera
-ms-overflow-style: none; //IE and Edge
```

You don't need to tell the kids what to span, the parent grid will instruct them in the order you declare them.
i.e. the sidebar will be 250px, the content will take up the remaining space (1fr).

Comment: Same issue as with other anwsers - it prevents from shrinking but it adds scrollbar to the entire page.

Comment: This is not the answer, it is really silly hack. There should not be page scrollbar at all, the only scrollbar I want is for the 900px element.